# How to get item details of abandoned cart?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart

I need to add a new column to show item names (comma seperated) in Abandoned cart grid. Which tables to be join with the parent collection to get item names ? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because abandoned carts pull from the `sales_flat_quote` table you should be able to join on `sales_flat_quote_item` and use the `name` field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How can I get products comma separately ? What is the obeserver event should I use to do this?

Comment: philwinkle, do you have any link which explains the relation between the products and the database tables? or is this can be known through pure experience only?